# Как в Angular 7 обойти все узлы с заданным классом и совершить некие манипуляции с ними?

Tags: angular, angular4, angular5

**Вот разметка**

```html
<!--my.component.html при загрузке страницы-->
<ul>
  <li class="active">Value 1</li>
  <li>Value 2</li>
  <li>Value 3</li>
 </ul>
```

**Задача**: по клику на элемент списка добавлять ему класс .active, а других этот класс убирать.

Трудно перестроиться после js/jquery, помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться. Как это изящно реализовать в angular7?

Comment: помочь разобраться в чем? нет желания помогать, когда человек не открывал документацию, такие вещи описаны на самых первых порах

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Angular предоставляет шаблонизатор, благодаря которому вы можете написать так:

**app.component.html**

```
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let i of items" (click)="select(i)" [class.active]="i.id == selected.id">{{ i.title }}</li>
</ul>
```

**app.component.ts**

```
public selected;
...
public select(item) {
  this.selected = item;
}
```